# Subversions: Working in local -> make changes into server?

Tags: svn, versions

I've decided to learn version control and I have zero knowledge. I've read some tutorials and articles about subversions some time now but just can't figure it out! :)

I have my current project in localhost atm and going to move it in my live server for first testing purpose and then offcourse releasing it for public. I still want to keep working it first localhost and then update working code into live server. I just don't know how to do it...

I have Versions in my Mac which I find really nice app.. well I think it is.

Could someone please provide me step-by-step guide what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preferred Solution**

- Move subversion repository to remote server
- Change local repository to use new remote server
- Commit changes as required

**Dual Master Repository Version**

- Use patch from local repository, copy to remote server, commit changes
- Checkout from the remote server, copy files from local repository, then commit back upstream
- Or just sync your subversion folder to the server for read-only access (removing private files if required)

**Pro's & Cons for 2 Master Repositories**

- **PRO:** Local repository can contain all sorts of private/restricted documents that are not copied to public repository
- **CON**: Patch/Change management needs to be done to ensure all changes are synced between both repositories
- **CON**: Cannot use any other developers as repository not available over the Internet
- **PRO**: Commits can be done into remote repository at specific revisions instead of uploading every commit made to local repository

**My 0.2 cents worth**

If you need to have files inside the SVN repository that you **don't** want shared with the world, use the 2 repository method, otherwise just use a single repository that is remotely hosted. Having only 1 master repository  will make life easier in the future and also change management procedures.